# Why is a new object not saved when adding it to a list of an existing object in EF4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I retrieve an existing customer from the database by it's id. This customer has a list of certificates. So I have: `customer.CertificatesAsInvestor`.

When I create a new certificate (`var cert = new Certificate()`) and add this object to the list `customer.CertificatesAsInvestor.Add(cert)` and then call `SaveChanges()`, the new certificate is not stored in the Database.

Why is this and what do I have to do to get this to work?

Customer class:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Deceased = false;
        this.CertificatesAsInvestor = new HashSet<Certificate>();
        this.CertificatesAsBeneficiary = new HashSet<Certificate>();
        this.BankAccounts = new HashSet<BankAccount>();
        this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        this.Documents = new HashSet<Document>();
        this.Name = new PersonName();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BSNNo { get; set; }
    public string IdCardNo { get; set; }
    public bool Deceased { get; set; }
    public Kompas.Bas.Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Kompas.Bas.Title Title { get; set; }
    public string DayPhone { get; set; }
    public string OtherPhone { get; set; }
    public Kompas.Bas.CustomerStatus Status { get; set; }

    public PersonName Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Certificate> CertificatesAsInvestor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Certificate> CertificatesAsBeneficiary { get; set; }
    public virtual Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Certificate:

```
public partial class Certificate
{
    public Certificate()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
        this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        this.Clicks = new HashSet<Click>();
        this.ParticipationCalculations = new HashSet<ParticipationCalculation>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CertificateNo { get; set; }
    public decimal NominalFee { get; set; }
    public bool IsSigned { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateIn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReturnDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateStop { get; set; }
    public Kompas.Bas.Paymethod Paymethod { get; set; }
    public Kompas.Bas.CertificateStatus Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DexContractNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CollectionId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FinalDateMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FinalDateMax { get; set; }
    public bool Gift { get; set; }
    public decimal PurchaseRate { get; set; }
    public decimal PurchaseRateDiscount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PayStopDate { get; set; }
    public decimal GuaranteeValue { get; set; }
    public int PaidTermCount { get; set; }
    public decimal DepositNominal { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SecondBirthDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer InvestingCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer BeneficiaryCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual InvestorRole InvestorRole { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual BankAccount CollectionBankAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual BankAccount PaymentBankAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual Origin Origin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Click> Clicks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParticipationCalculation> ParticipationCalculations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your customer and certificate class definitions.

Comment: `InvestigatingCustomer` is a property of your `Certificate` class, not your `Customer` class.

Comment: @JoeEnos My bad, I've updated my post, it had to be `customer.CertificatesAsInvestor`

Comment: Can you show the code where you retrieve the customer from the context, add the cert, and save it? Basically, just need to make sure the context stays open, and the customer belongs to that context, for the entire time.

Comment: @JoeEnos I think the context is still open because when I do this: `certificate.InvestingCustomer = customer;
                        this.uow.Certificates.AddObject(certificate);` it works. I get a new certificate record.